# click operation on iframe div from parent in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to perform an operation on the basis of iframe button click.But i am unable to do it.

HTML :-

```
<div class="content">
    Here my content displaying
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#ifrme_btn').click(function(){
        console.log('button clicked');
        $('#message_div', window.parent.document).hide();
      });

    });
    </script>
      <div id="message_div">
            After click on iframe button i want hide this div
    </div>

    <iframe id="Iframe">
    <html lang="en-US" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Any Title</title>
    </head>
    <body id="ifrme-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
           <input type="button" id="ifrme_btn" name="Check Status" value="Clicked Iframe Button" />
    </body>
    </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

onclick on `ifrme_btn` i want hide `message_div`

Answer (score 0):

Use .live("click") if you're interacting with an generated element.

> http://api.jquery.com/live/

For example:

```
$("#ifrme_btn").live("click", function(){
    $("#message_div").hide();   
    }
});
```

Comment: Just add the closing bracket. Sorry I have wrote that in a hurry, I'm at work ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that in jQuery 1.7 `.live()` is depreciated and 1.9+ it is removed, instead `.on()` should be used with the same syntax.

Comment: he meant "worth mentioning" and yes, the correct method is on() because of the aformentioned reasons.. thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

The function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#ifrme_btn').click(function(){
        console.log('button clicked');
        $('#message_div', window.parent.document).hide();
      });

    });
```

Should be inside your iframe, not in the main document.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

**HTML**

```
  <iframe name="Iframe" id="Frame"></iframe>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('[name=Iframe]').contents().find('#ifrme_btn').click(function() {
  $('#message_div').hide();
});
```